# javascript copying element value, where element name has a period

Tags: javascript

If an html element id has no period in it, then copying between elements is of course trivial, e.g.:

```
 var theForm = document.paymentForm;
 theForm.BillStreet1.value = theForm.ShipStreet1.value;
```

I've got a case where I need to have period in my ids, namely id="bill.street1" and id="ship.street1", and the following doesn't work :-(

```
 theForm.bill.street1.value = theForm.ship.street1.value;
```

Can you please let me know how to handle the period?  Does jquery make this simpler?

Comment: FYI - I'm using sub-objects in grails, and need to access them this way (dot notation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery makes everything simplier by using css selectors to access elements. However, if you don't want to use jQuery, you can access the element this way, I believe.

```
theForm['bill.street1'].value = theForm['ship.street1'].value;
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work because periods are an alternate method to access an array, iirc.

Be sure to use `theForm['bill.street1'].value = theForm['ship.street1'].value;`
and not `theForm.['bill.street1'].value = theForm.['ship.street1'].value;`. The extra periods make the format invalid, in the same way using `array.[2]` instead of `array[2]` would invalidate it.

Comment: hmm, thanks for your response.  I can't get this to work for some reason.

Comment: In fact, when I use this syntax, I get a javascript error (as shown in firebug): "missing name after . operator."  The alerts I have ahead of this statement don't even work anymore (this is in Firefox).

Comment: Ah, I think I know what the issue is... Did you use `theForm.['bill.street1'].value = theForm.['ship.street1'].value;` rather than `theForm['bill.street1'].value = theForm['ship.street1'].value;`? If I use the former syntax I get the same error in Firebug.

Comment: Fantastic Yoshiyahu.  You got it, good catch.  It must be getting late!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Haha, javascript is a powerful tool, but it definitely gets tiresome when it comes to node traversing.

Answer (score 3):

```
theForm['bill.street1'].value
theForm['ship.street1'].value
```

Comment: I can't get theForm['bill.street1'].value = theForm['ship.street1'].value;
  to work for some reason.

Comment: In fact, when I use this syntax, I get a javascript error (as shown in firebug): "missing name after . operator."  The alerts I have ahead of this statement don't even work anymore (this is in Firefox).